# Azure Orchestration Function: How to get Http request header?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have an HTTP trigger that calls an orchestration function:

```
    [FunctionName("HttpStart")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, methods: "post", Route = "orchestrators/{functionName}")] HttpRequestMessage req,
        [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClientBase starter,
        string functionName,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // Function input comes from the request content.
        dynamic eventData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
        string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(functionName, eventData);
```

The header of the orchestration function looks like this:

```
public static async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContextBase context, TraceWriter log)
```

Given that I don't have an HTTP context in the orchestration function, how can I forward a request header into the orchestration function from the HTTP trigger?

Comment: have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management#start-instances parameter input

Answer (score 0):

[Took a look at this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#http-api-url-discovery) :

```html
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask"
#r "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    HttpRequestMessage req,
    DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    string functionName,
    ILogger log)
{
    // Function input comes from the request content.
    dynamic eventData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(functionName, eventData);
    
    log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
    
    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}
```